# In C++ an algorithm that can be used to determine whether a Stack object S has exactly one element

Tags: c++

> Develop an algorithm that can be used to determine whether a Stack object S has exactly one element.

I am not a programmer, I choose this course as an elective to see if I would be interested. I don't know where to begin with this question.

Comment: I'd start from reading C++ book / tutorial. Most would cover the key elements to answer this quite early. Or at least you'll be able to understand the question and attempt a solution, which will have much better odds of getting you help. Good luck!

Comment: What's a 'stack'? `std::stack`?

Comment: I'm going to disagree with the first comment. Don't start with a C++ book. Don't start with most programming texts. Start with logic. Learn logic first. Too many folks either leap into or  are thrown into programming before they have a good grasp on how to attack a problem, break it down, and logically construct a solution. Once you can do that then the mechanics of the language start to come into play. If you just start slinging code out, you'll find you do much unnecessary rewriting and debugging and come to hate programming.

Comment: @norok2 "*I'd start from reading C++ book / tutorial*" - I'd start with talking to the instructor, because they are clearly not explaining the subject matter very well. Students should not be tackling this assignment if they haven't been introduced to the basic concepts of containers yet.

Answer (score 3):

You most likely want to check the documentation of C++ on stacks. This took no time to find:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/size/

Your function has to return `stack.size() == 1`.  If the question is asking to develop an algorithm based on the size in memory the stack size allocates then it's slightly more involved.

Comment: I generally find *cppreference.com* to be the more authoritative and informational, e.g. [std::stack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack). Also worth mentioning that a function would simply be a waste of a function call, since you correctly note a simple `if (stack.size() == 1)` answers the question. a function doing `bool stacksz1 (std::stack& s) { return s.size() == 1; }` would be superfluous unless inlined.